# Bound datagridview not accepting new rows

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a form with a dgv and at the top of the form I have:

```
Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim da1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim myBuilder As MySqlCommandBuilder
Dim bsource As New BindingSource
```

Then I bound the dgv with:

```
 Try
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(gen.connString)
            Dim sql As String
            sql = "SELECT ID, RoomType, RateCode, StandardPrice, Adults, Children, AdditionalAdult, AdditionalChild FROM rates " _
                    & "WHERE RateCode = @rateCode"
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
                da1.SelectCommand = cmd
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rateCode", gen.strIDtoOpen)
            End Using
            ds1.Reset()
            dt.Clear()
            ds1.Reset()
            conn.Open()
            da1.Fill(ds1, "rats")
            conn.Close()
            myBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da1)
            dt = ds1.Tables("rats")
            bsource.DataSource = dt
        End Using
        dgvRoomTypes.DataSource = bsource
        isDirty = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbExclamation, "Unexpected Error")
    End Try
```

I then add new rows to the dataset (ds1) with:

```
ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Add({id, roomType, gen.strIDtoOpen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})
ds1.AcceptChanges()
```

The new rows display nicely in the dgv. Then I save to back to the table using:

```
dgvRoomTypes.CurrentCell = Nothing
da1.Update(ds1, "rats")
```

For some reason, edits to existing rows get saved to the table but new rows, even though they appear nicely on the dgv, don't get saved the table. I have probably used this routine hundreds of times but I have spent hours and cant seem to find what I'm missing

Comment: Why are you calling `AcceptChanges`? Do you know what it actually does? It would appear not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, you right. I'm actually not sure what it does. Whiles I looked for help, that was a solution proposed on another site

Comment: And believe it or not @jmcilhinney, that was the problem. I took that `AcceptChanges` out and it works

Comment: You should read the documentation for that method to learn what it does. If you understand that then you will know how and why it works in certain situations and not in others. Note that the `DataSet` has an `AcceptChanges` method that calls the `AcceptChanges` method of each `DataTable`, which calls `AcceptChanges` on each `DataRow`. It's the row's method that actually does something to that row.

Comment: I believe it. :-)

Comment: Thank you :-)...

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, a datarow is an intelligent array of data; you typically download it from a database or create it anew if you aim to save data to a database. A datarow tracks changes to all its properties so it can give you, at any moment, the original and the current version of each column's value on the row and it maintains a state to know a few things about what has happened to it

A row downloaded from a DB as a [RowState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowstate?view=netcore-3.1) of Unchanged. If you change something, it becomes Modified. If you delete it it becomes Deleted. If you add a new row to a table, it is Added. If you pull a row out of a table or have created it but haven't yet added it to a table, it is Detached

When you save a datatable, the RowState determines the query that will be run when the adapter Update is called. Update on an adapter should be thought of as "SaveChangesToDb", NOT an UPDATE query. Update iterates the rows looking at the row state:

- Added - an INSERT is run
- Modified - an UPDATE is run
- Deleted - a DELETE is run

After the operation is carried out, AcceptChanges may be run on the row by the adapter, resetting its state to Unchanged (for update/insert) or removing it from the datatable (Deleted)

---

Critically, if YOU call AcceptChanges, you reset the state, meaning there is nothing that will be saved; all rows are marked as Unchanged